# How can I properly pass stdin inputs to my Python subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using a CLI program, [age](https://github.com/FiloSottile/age), to encrypt files with a passphrase. You cannot supply the passphrase as an argument or an environment variable; after the program starts, it prompts you to type it in. This is a pain to encrypt a large number of files, so I'm writing a Python script to do it for me:

```
def age_encrypt(filename: str):
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        [
            "age",
            "--passphrase",
            "--output",
            filename + ".age",
            filename,
        ],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    )
    p.communicate(input=b"some_passphrase\n")
```

This works perfectly when I try it with my own program as the subprocess instead of age. But when I run age, it doesn't work: the prompt still appears to me, and my Python program doesn't communicate with it.

I've read the documentation for the subprocess module, but I can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: The routine that program uses for reading the passphrase is [here](https://github.com/FiloSottile/age/blob/main/cmd/age/age.go#L289). At a glance, it looks like age prompts for the passwords twice, but you're only providing it once. Is there no error message being produced?

Comment: If you're not committed to using age specifically, you might want to try out Xecrets File Cli, https://github.com/xecrets/xecrets-file-cli . It supports your needs, and more. (Disclosure - I am the author of it. More info at https://www.axantum.com/ .)